# Why are my last two variables not inserting into the database?

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason my last two variables will not input into the database. I am referring to `$verifyKey` and `$keyExpire`.  Here is my code with comments. I am adding the entire page to make sure I don't have the wrong character somewhere it isn't supposed to be. Effectively this is a registration page that inserts the information into the database and gives a verification key for email verification later.

I have the fields matched up with the code in the database and they are set to longtext and text. I don't want to insert directly as I am trying to get this method to work with all 5 variables.

```
<?php

// This is not seen by the end user so this file is placed in the unseen folder
// Check if the user used the sign up button


if (isset($_POST['signup-submit'])) {
    // uses the database handler
    require 'dbh.php';
    $username=$_POST['uid'];
    $email=$_POST['mail'];
    $password=$_POST['pwd'];
    $passwordcnfrm=$_POST['pwd-cnfrm'];
    $verifyKey=md5(time().$username);
    $keyExpire=date("U")+ 86400;


    // Checks to see if any field are empty
    if(empty($username)||empty($email)||empty($password)||empty($passwordcnfrm)) {

        // This header returns the username and/or email address so the user doesn't have to retype it
        header("Location:../signup.php?error=emptyfields&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);

        exit();
    }
    // Checks if both the user and email are invalid
    else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)&&!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/",$username)) {
        header("Location:../signup.php?error=invalidmailuid");
        exit();
    }
    // Checks if the email is valid
    else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location:../signup.php?error=invalidmail&uid=".$username);
        exit();
    }
    // Checks if the username is valid.
    else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/",$username)) {
        header("Location:../signup.php?error=invaliduid&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    }
    // Checks to see if the password and confirm password match
    else if ($password !== $passwordcnfrm){
        header("Location:../signup.php?error=passwordcheck&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    }
    // Checks to see if the username is already in use or password is invalid
    else {

        $sql = "SELECT uidUsers FROM users WHERE uidUsers=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
            header("Location:../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        }
        else {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$username);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows();
                if ($resultCheck < 0){
                    header("Location:../signup.php?error=usertaken&mail=".$email);
                    exit();
                }
                else {
                    //Inserts into database

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers,emailUsers,pwdUsers,verify,expires) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);";
                    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

                    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
                        header("Location:../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
                        exit();
                    }
                    else {
                        $hashedPwd =password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sssss",$username,$email,$hashedPwd,$verifyKey,$keyExpire);
                        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                        header("Location:../signup.php?signup=success");

                    }

                }    
            }   
        }
    //Closes session to db
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);

}
else {
    header("Location:../signup.php");
}
```

Comment: `header("Location:../signup.php?error=invaliduid&mail=".$email);` might be prone to [HTTP Response Splitting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Response_Splitting) and can basically be used for Cross Scripting Attacks... I believe this vulnerability was patched in the more modern PHP versions (5.4.38+)

Comment: I just switched to 7.3. Good looking out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In description of `mysqli_stmt::bind_param` there is this criptic note:

> If data size of a variable exceeds max. allowed packet size
>   (max_allowed_packet), you have to specify b in types and use
>   `mysqli_stmt_send_long_data()` to send the data in packets.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Practically it means that for every longtext (and blob) field you have to additionally call `mysqli_stmt_send_long_data` after `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`. Otherwise you have this strange behavious when everything works ok, but fields are not set.

Comment: I added these and same result.  I am also using this same method on my password reset form and it is putting the hashed information into the database.